# Nightwatch + phantomJS: how to get logs from console

Tags: phantomjs, e2e-testing, nightwatch.js

I do the next test with nightwatch:

```
var page = browser.page.certificats();
page
  .navigate()
  .section.search
  .waitForElementNotPresent('@loader', 1000);
  .waitForElementPresent('@option', 2000)
```

On firefox and chrome, all work fine. With phantomJS, the test fails because it doesn't find the @option.
The @option element is build by some JS code.
I suspect a JS error but I can't get the JS error in console with phantomJS.

How can I get theses logs ?

Thanks.